# Unable to delete 64 bit registry key in Delphi 7

Tags: delphi

I am trying to delete 64 bit registry key with 32 bit application in Delphi 7. I have written the following code to accomplish the same but am getting "error code 87 - Invalid parameter specified".

```
Procedure DeleteRegistryKeyEx(RootKey : HKEY; KeyToDelete : String) ;
Var
      DllHandle : THandle;
      RegDeleteKeyExA : Function (Key : HKEY; lpSubKey : LPCTSTR ; samDesired : REGSAM ; reserved : DWORD) : Integer;
     KeyName   ,
     ErrBuff   : Array[0..MAX_PATH] of Char;
 begin
      DllHandle := LoadLibrary(PChar('advapi32.dll')) ;
      KeyName   := #0;
      ErrBuff   := #0;
     Try
           If DllHandle > 0 Then
           Begin
           Try
                RegDeleteKeyExA := GetProcAddress(DllHandle,'RegDeleteKeyExA');
                If @RegDeleteKeyExA <> nil then
                begin
                   ErrCode := -1;
                   StrPCopy(KeyName , '123') ;
                   hKey1 := 0;
                   ErrCode := -1;
               ErrCode := RegOpenKeyEx( HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SOFTWARE',
                          0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS Or $0100, hkey1);
                   If ErrCode = 0 Then               
                   Begin
                       ErrCode := -1;
                       ErrCode := RegDeleteKeyExA(hKey1 , KeyName , $0100 , 0);
                       If ErrCode =  ERROR_SUCCESS Then
                          WriteLn('Key deleted by Ex')
                       Else
                       Begin
                        ErrBuff :=#0;
                        FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM,nil,ErrCode,0, ErrBuff, SizeOf(ErrBuff),nil);
                        //error msg in ErrBuff for error in RegDeleteKeyExA 
                       end;
       End
       Else
       Begin
         ErrBuff := #0;
         FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM,nil,ErrCode,0, ErrBuff, SizeOf(ErrBuff),nil);
         // Error code in ErrBuff for error in RegopenKeyEx 
       End;

     end
   Except
    On E:Exception Do
   End;
End;
 Finally
  Try
     If DllHandle > 0 Then
       FreeLibrary(DllHandle) ;
  Except

  End;

 End;
 end;
```

I am trying to delete key "123" under "HKLM\Software". openKey is successful but DeleteKeyExA returns error 87. I dont know where I am going. 
I tested this code under windows 64 bit XP professional.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a calling convention mismatch. The function needs to be `stdcall`, but your declaration will use the default `register` convention. Fix it like this:

```
RegDeleteKeyExA: function(Key: HKEY; lpSubKey: LPCTSTR; samDesired: REGSAM;
    reserved: DWORD): Integer; stdcall;
```

---

I have some other comments on your code, which you can take or leave.

Rather than checking `>0` on the module handle, check `<>0`. The module handle should be declared as `HMODULE` rather than `THandle`. The latter is something that you close with `CloseHandle`, and a module handle is not such a thing.

I think the code would benefit from the declaration of a constant:

```
const
  KEY_WOW64_64KEY = $0100;
```

And for the text parameters, I would declare them as strings, and use a `PChar` to obtain a pointer to null terminated string.

```
var
  KeyName: string;
....
KeyName := '123';
....
ErrCode := RegDeleteKeyExA(hKey1, PChar(KeyName), KEY_WOW64_64KEY, 0);
```